# Install an exe file using C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, installation

I need to install an application file (.exe or .msi) programmatically using c#. Is that possible. I cant able to find out a method for that. Please update me if anyone have idea on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For msi: 
if you don't want control installation process. just use

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " /quiet /i Setup.msi ADDLOCAL=test";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

If you want controll process of installation, you must create bootstraper.
4example with wixsharp or wix. Or native c++. Or burn)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications/